# how to initial array when reverse string

Tags: c++

the question is about leetcode 344. Reverse String

```
class Solution {
public:
    string reverseString(string s) {
        char *array = new char[s.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {    
            array[i] =s[s.length()-i-1];
        }
        string strlist(array);
        printf("%s\n",strlist.c_str());
        return strlist;
    }
};
```

input is "Sore was I ere I saw Eros."
output is ".sorE was I ere I saw eroSnam A\""

it seems that my array has more element than I expected, and I have no idea how to avoid that, anyone can suggest that?

Comment: You forgot to terminate the string with `'\0'`.

Comment: Why `new char[]`? Especially when you're already using `std::string` everywhere?

Comment: Why not simply -- `string reverseString(string s) { std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end()); return s; }`?

Comment: Don't mix C (e.g. char arrays, naked owning pointers, printf) and C++ (std::string, smart pointers, algorithms, iostream).

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to terminate the C-style string with a null character. Also remember to `delete[]` the allocated array.

```
string reverseString(string s) {
    char *array = new char[s.length() + 1];
    //                                ^^^
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {    
        array[i] =s[s.length()-i-1];
    }
    array[s.length()] = 0; // Terminate the string
    string strlist(array);
    printf("%s\n",strlist.c_str());
    delete [] array; // Don't forget
    return strlist;
}
```

There's also some neat ways to do it:

```
std::string t(s);
std::reverse(t.begin(), t.end());
return t;
```

Or:

```
return std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
```